# AWS Redshift UNPIVOT semi structured data will skip blank values

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, partiql

following is my data set and table structure

```
create table students (
    student_id varchar(255),
    contact_numbers super   
)
```

```
student_id, contact_numbers
    1      {"mobile":111,"office":222}
    2      {"mobile":4444}
    3      {"mobile":555}
    5      {"mobile":8888}
    6      {}
    7      {}
    8      {}
    9      {"office":222}
```

i want to unpivot contact numbers, but when unpivoting blank values will be remove from the result.

**unpivote query**

```
SELECT student_id, attr, val FROM students tb,
UNPIVOT tb.contact_numbers AS val AT attr
```

result

```
student_id, attr,   val
1           mobile  111
1           office  222
2           mobile  4444
3           mobile  555
5           mobile  8888
9           office  222
```

you can see 6, 7 and 8 student ids are missing from the result. i want to get all student ids from the result

when i run the below query with the left join, student ids are missing from the result. i need those student ids and null or blank values

```
select student_id, attr, val  from students tb
LEFT JOIN tb.contact_numbers contact ON true,
UNPIVOT tb.contact_numbers AS val AT attr
```

expected result

```
student_id, attr,   val
1           mobile  111
1           office  222
2           mobile  4444
3           mobile  555
5           mobile  8888
6
7
8
9           office  222
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the values attributes don't exist for these students.  So there is nothing unpivot.  There are a number of ways to attack this but you will likely want to LEFT join student id to this info.  This way you know all student id exist in the output.

You could also pre-condition your data, or UNION and group by.  The bottom line is you cannot unpivot with what doesn't exist.

UPDATE:

Left joining to add the full list of student_id values will look like (untested):

```
SELECT b.student_id, a.attr, a.val
FROM students b
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT student_id, attr, val 
  FROM students tb,
  UNPIVOT tb.contact_numbers AS val AT attr ) a
ON a.student_id = b.student_id
ORDER BY b.student_id;
```

Comment: but when i add left join with unpivot keyword it gives me an error on redshift. could you please share the correct sql query for that ?

Comment: Can you post what you are doing?  I suspect you may have misinterpreted my answer.  I mean you should join the result from your query above with the original table in an outer level select.

Comment: i updated the question. could you please check ?

Comment: Not what I was going for.  I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: i tried out but it's not working same output

Comment: Sorry, this is what happens when you write SQL on the fly.  The FROM targets were reversed (or it needed to be RIGHT JOIN).  It is fixed in the answer now.